# D3 Line Transition with JSON Data from Database

Tags: php, sql, json, d3.js, transition

I followed the guide from Mike Boston.

https://gist.github.com/mbostock/1642874

And what i want is a moving line like in this fiddle i found.

http://jsfiddle.net/peDzT/

My problem is its easy to handle with formated static data from csv or whatever.

But i get my data via php from my mssql database and store them in variables.

```
// Get the data
<php php echo "data=" .$json_data.";" ?>
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.Datum = parseDate(d.Datum);
d.Temp = +d.Temp;
})
```

the json looks like for example this with 80 items from my sql selection:

$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT TOP 80 Datum, Temp, OfenNr etc.

```
[{"Datum":"2016-03-03 14:19:15.000","Temp":"23.25","OfenNr":"1"},{"Datum":"2016-03-03 14:19:08.000","Temp":"23.25","OfenNr":"1"},{"Datum":"2016-03-03 14:19:01.000","Temp":"23.0","OfenNr":"1"},{"Datum":"2016-03-03 14:18:55.000","Temp":"23.25","OfenNr":"1"}]
```

I get this datas in a interval i want.
So the question is how push i my given new datapoints into my line graph???

```
function next () {
    return {
        Datum: function(d) { return d.Datum },
        Temp: function(d) { return d.Temp }
    };
}

tick();

function tick() {
transition = transition.each(function () {

    // update the domains
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.Datum; }));


    // push a new data point onto the back
    data.push(next());

    // redraw the line, and slide it to the left
    path.attr("d", line)
        .attr("transform", null);

    // slide the x-axis left, rescale the y-axis
    axis.call(x.axis);
    yAx.call(y.axis);


    // slide the line left
    path.transition()
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + x - 1 + ")");

    // pop the old data point off the front
    data.shift();
}).transition().each("start", tick);
```

my problem is how to work with my json data.